# avoiding for loop for matrix calculations

Tags: matlab, performance, for-loop, coding-efficiency

I am coding in matlab and since matlab does not work well with "for" loops I need to avoid them so I can make it as fast as possible. Here is a part of my code which is dealing with "for".

```
for i = 1:size(U,1)
    for j=1:size(U,2)        
        v(i,j) = U(mod(i+1-1,size(U,1))+1,j) + U(i,mod(j+1-1,size(U,2))+1) ...
               + U(mod(i-1-1,size(U,1))+1,j) + U(i,mod(j-1-1,size(U,2))+1) - 4*U(i,j);
    end 
end
```

There is a periodic boundary condition in my matrix, that's why I am using "mod" functions.
This code is actually similar to "del2" function in matlab, but matlab version is not working with periodic boundary condition.

Comment: please explain what you mean by matlab does not work well with "for" loops

Comment: @BradDay It can increase the runtime of a simulation if you use too many "for" loops, and if you write the same code in another language programming like C++ it would be faster. Anyway, I am looking for an alternative for loops structures like "for", that's it ...

Comment: Hmm. I don't see a way this can be done without an iterative process since you need to look at the neighbors of U(i,j) for the Laplacian. The only thing I could suggest if matlab is executing the code too slowly is to try utilizing a parallel for loop with [parfor](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html)

Answer (score 0):

Vectorised version using [`meshgrid`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html):

```
[n,m] = meshgrid(1:size(U,2),1:size(U,1));
v = U(sub2ind(size(U),mod(m,size(U,1))+1,n)) + U(sub2ind(size(U),m,mod(n,size(U,2))+1)) ...
    + U(sub2ind(size(U),mod(m-2,size(U,1))+1,n)) + U(sub2ind(size(U),m,mod(n-2,size(U,2))+1)) - 4.*U;
```

You could also speed up the loop (likely by multiple orders of magnitude) by [preallocating memory](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html). In this case, just put

```
v = zeros(size(U));
```

in front of the loop.